# Delete items from cart while adding new products in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to delete items from cart while adding new products. I am observing : `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event for this. My code is following:

```
<checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
    <observers>
        <secodaryproduct>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>secodaryproduct/observer</class>
            <method>checkoutCartAddProductAddComplete</method>
        </secodaryproduct>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
```

And for deleting products:

```
 $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
 $quote->removeItem($product['item_id']);
 $quote->save();
```

When i call this code without observer then this works fine and delete required items. But if i use this using observer then items not deleting from cart. I have also put the output in log file and item ids are printing correctly but my items are not deleting from cart. 
Please help.

Comment: where does `$product['item_id']` comes from ? Be aware that you have to use the ids of the items of the quote to remove them via `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeItem($itemId)` and not a product id of some sort.

Comment: Yes $product['item_id'] is the id of  the record of "sales_flat_quote_item". And I have printed the item id in log file and this is showing correctly. Only delete query is not working in case of checkout_cart_add_product_complete event but this is working fine in case of checkout_cart_update_items_after and sales_quote_remove_item events.

Answer (score 0):

When `Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete', ...)` gets invoked in `/checkout/cart/add`, the relevant `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` instance gets passed to the event observers. So you should be able to do something like this, which will remove all cart items matching that product ID:

```
public function checkoutCartAddProductAddComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    /* @var Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart */
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cartItems = $cart->getItems();
    /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductId() == $product->getId()) {
            $cart->removeItem($item->getId());
        }
    }
    $cart->save();
}
```

Comment: I have item id of item to be deleted but not able to perform delete due to some reason. According to solution given by you i can get item id but delete will still not work.

Comment: @GaganpreetKaur - In your example `$product['item_id']` would not be set during the event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`. I updated my example to have `$cart->save()` after the item deletion since I just threw it together before but hadn’t tested it. Now it works to remove any cart items matching the **product ID** passed to the event. You will have to modify it to fit your needs.